# How to save videos recorded from a loop as different files?

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I'm recording videos in a loop using opencv and python. I've managed to get it to record and save all the videos from the loop to a single output file, but my goal is to get every video recorded in the loop saved as a different file, with the date and time as the identifier for each video. I don't use python very much and I'm sure there is a simple way to do it but I just can't find it. Any help is much appreciated!

```
import cv2
import time as t1
import numpy as np

def save_video(outPath,fps,mirror=False):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    currentFrame = 0
    width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)  # float
    height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)  # float

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(outPath, fourcc, 20.0, (int(width), int(height)))

    while (cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            if mirror == True:
                frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    else:
        break
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    currentFrame +=1


    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

date_string = t1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")

count=0
while(True):
    if count < 6:
    print('Recording started: recording video number ' + str(count))
    save_video('/Documents/0222_video_recordings/video' + date_string + '.avi', 
    30.0,mirror=True)
    count += 1
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? You already know how to write videos to a file, right?

Comment: Yep, but if I run this code every video it captures (from the six I want it to) get saved to the same file. I want each video to get saved to a separate file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select different file name in each iteration.

Example:

```
save_video('/Documents/0222_video_recordings/video_' + str(count) + '_' + date_string + '.avi',
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2, numpy as np
import time
from datetime import datetime
i = 1;

win_name = 'Recording'

start_time = time.time()
capture_duration = 1

# Connect camera for capture 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)              
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080) 
# cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS,150)

frame_width = int(cap.get(3))

frame_height = int(cap.get(4))

frame_size = (frame_width,frame_height)

#output = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), 20, (frame_width , frame_height))
outVid = 'output_' + str(i) + '.avi'
output = cv2.VideoWriter( outVid, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), 20, (frame_width , frame_height))
while cap.isOpened():
    e1 = cv2.getTickCount()       
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    minutes = int(duration/60)
    hours = int(minutes/60)
    seconds = duration%60
    seconds = round(seconds, 2)
    now = datetime.now()
    # write text to the frame
    cv2.putText(frame, now.strftime("date : %Y/%m/%d time : %H:%M:%S") + '  '+ 'hours: ' + str(hours) + '  min: ' + str(minutes) + '  sec: ' + str(seconds), (20, frame_height - 20), 0, 1, (255, 255, 255), 1,
          cv2.LINE_AA)

   
    cv2.imshow(win_name, frame)
    # print(round(seconds % 20))

    if round(minutes) < capture_duration:

        output.write(frame)

    elif round(minutes) == capture_duration:
        output.release()
        i += 1
        capture_duration += 1
        outVid = 'output_' + str(i) + '.avi'
        output = cv2.VideoWriter( outVid, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), 20, (frame_width , frame_height))
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)  & 0xFF
    if key == 27:    # Esc, 종료
            break          


else:
    print("can't open camera.")

cap.release()                          
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
output.release()
```

Comment: Try this ...it records vids in 1 minute loops. This duration can be altered in the if round(minutes) < capture_duration loop

Answer (score 0):

i can help you , but my answer is not much useful.......
you can use this code .......

```
import cv2
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc("*XVID")

# out = cv2.VideoWriter("out.avi", codec, frame speed, frame size)
out = cv2.VideoWriter("out.avi", codec, 10.0, (640,480))
i = 0

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret == True:

        cv2.VideoWriter("out{}.avi".format(i),fourcc, 10.0, (640,480)).write(frame)

        i = i + 1

    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == ord("q"):

        break

cap.release()

out.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.